# Can I change in app purchase price that is ready for sale ? without entering review again?

Tags: iphone, ios

Just to be sure.

I have application with in app purchase, ready for sale state.
If I change the price, this will be effective immediatly(or 24 hours..the same) or this will need disable the in app purchase item, and need to go for apple review ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, if you change the price it will be immediate although the change is not REALLY immediate. The change has to populate to all iTunes servers, so for a short period of time, some stores may have it at different prices. But the time is usually less than an hour or two.

The point of the review is to review functionality, the price is in your hands.

Answer (score 2):

"ready for sale" app's price modification does not put app in review again. review is ment for testing the app functionality not pricing!!